# Не могу нормально запушить данные в двусвязный список

Tags: c

Не могу нормально запушить данные в двусвязный список. Выводит столько раз значения последнего элемента, сколько элементов было всего(затирает предыдущие данные)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <conio.h>

//***********СТРУКТУРЫ******************************************
typedef struct t_Book
{
    char genre[30];  //Жанр книги
    char title[50];  //Название книги
    char author[50]; //Имя автора
    int year;        //Год издания
    int pagesNumber; //Количество страниц
    bool isAvailable;//Есть в наличии в библиотеке
} Book;

typedef struct _Node {
    Book *value;
    struct _Node *next;
    struct _Node *prev;
} Node;

typedef struct _DblLinkedList {
    size_t size;
    Node *head;
    Node *tail;
} DblLinkedList;
//***************************************************************

//***********ПРОТОТИПЫ ФУНКЦИЙ***********************************
void menu(void);                                        //главное меню
void getHelp(void);                                     //навигация по действиям
void getEnter(void);                                    //отображение Help после нажатие Enter
Book createBook(void);
DblLinkedList *createDblLinkedList(void);               //создание двусвязного списка
void deleteDblLinkedList(DblLinkedList *list);         //удаление двусвязного списка
void pushFront(DblLinkedList *list, Book *book); //добавление в начало списка
void getAllBooks(DblLinkedList *library);
//***************************************************************


int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    puts("Вы в главном меню программы");

    menu();

    return 0;
}
//***************************************************************
void getHelp(){
    printf("\n\n1 - Добавить книгу");
    printf("\n2 - Удалить книгу");
    printf("\n3 - Вывести информацию о книгах в виде таблицы");
    printf("\n4 - Поиск книги по фильтру");
    printf("\n5 - Количество книг по жанру");
    printf("\n6 - Поиск книг начиная с * года");
    printf("\n7 - Посмотреть список выданых книг");
    printf("\n8 - Отсортировать книги автора по году издания");

    printf("\n0 - Выйти из программы\n");
    printf("\nВыберите действие: ");
}

//***************************************************************
void menu(){
    int choise;
    Book elem;
    DblLinkedList *library = createDblLinkedList();
    do{

    getHelp();

    scanf("%d", &choise);

    switch(choise) {

    case 1:
        elem = createBook();
        pushFront(library, &elem);
        getEnter();
        break;
    case 2:
        puts("Выполнение функции 2");
        getEnter();
        break;
    case 3:
        getAllBooks(library);
        getEnter();
        break;
    case 4:
        puts("\nВыполнение функции 4");
        getEnter();
        break;
    case 5:
        puts("\nВыполнение функции 5");
        getEnter();
        break;
    case 6:
        puts("\nВыполнение функции 6");
        getEnter();
        break;
    case 7:
        puts("\nВыполнение функции 7");
        getEnter();
        break;
    case 8:
        puts("\nВыполнение функции 8");
        getEnter();
        break;
    case 0:
        exit(1);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Ошибка ввода, повторите попытку");
        getEnter();
        break;
        }
    }while(choise != 0);

    deleteDblLinkedList(library);
}
//***************************************************************
void getAllBooks(DblLinkedList *library){
    puts("Название\tЖанр\tАвтор\t\tГод издания\tКол-во страниц");
    Node *book = library->head;
    while (book != NULL) {
        printf("%s",  book->value->title);
        printf("\t%s",  book->value->genre);
        printf("\t%s",  book->value->author);
        printf("\t%d",  book->value->year);
        printf("\t\t%d\n",  book->value->pagesNumber);
        book = book->next;
    }
}

void getEnter(){
    printf("\nНажмите Enter, чтобы вывести меню");

    getch();
}
//***************************************************************
Book createBook(){
    Book book;
    printf("\nВведите жанр книги: ");
    scanf("%s", book.genre);
    printf("Введите название книги: ");
    scanf("%s", book.title);
    printf("Введите автора книги: ");
    scanf("%s", book.author);
    printf("Введите год издания книги: ");
    scanf("%d", &book.year);
    printf("Введите количество страниц книги: ");
    scanf("%d", &book.pagesNumber);
    return book;
}

DblLinkedList *createDblLinkedList() {
    DblLinkedList *tmp = (DblLinkedList*) malloc(sizeof(DblLinkedList));
    tmp->size = 0;
    tmp->head = tmp->tail = NULL;

    return tmp;
}
//***************************************************************
void deleteDblLinkedList(DblLinkedList *list) {
    Node *tmp = (list)->head;
    Node *next = NULL;
    while (tmp) {
        next = tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
        tmp = next;
    }
    free(list);
    (list) = NULL;
}
//***************************************************************
void pushFront(DblLinkedList *list, Book *book) {
    Node *tmp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    if (tmp == NULL) {
        exit(1);
    }

    tmp->value = book;
    tmp->next = list->head;
    tmp->prev = NULL;
    if (list->head) {
        list->head->prev = tmp;
    }
    list->head = tmp;

    if (list->tail == NULL) {
        list->tail = tmp;
    }
    list->size++;
}
//***************************************************************
```

Comment: У вас все списки ссылаются на одну область памяти, поэтому вы выводите только 1 элемент. Посмотрите на ваш `createBook()` внимательно.

Answer (score 1):

У вас все списки ссылаются на одну структуру определенную в `menu()`. Вы передаете в метод `pushFront()` один и тот же указатель. Вам необходимо подумать о том чтобы выделять память на каждую структуру `Book` отдельно.

Поэтому вам показалось что предыдущие значения затираются, на самом деле вы просто передавали один и тот же указатель в каждый `Node`.

Answer (score 1):

В функции `menu` вы используете одну и ту же локальную переменную `elem`, адрес которой заносите в список.

Вам надо динамически выделять память для каждой новой книги.

Соответствующий код может выглядеть следующим образом

```
void menu(){
    int choise;
    Book *elem = NULL;
    DblLinkedList *library = createDblLinkedList();
    do{

    getHelp();

    scanf("%d", &choise);

    switch(choise) {

    case 1:
        elem = malloc( sizeof( Book ) );
        *elem = createBook();
        pushFront(library, elem);
        getEnter();
        break;
    // ...
```